# Change search to case insensitive for MonoDevelop 4.0.1

Tags: monodevelop

As per title, I can't find the option to change the default search behaviour from case sensitive, which it's stuck in, to case insensitive.  It's not on the Tools->Options menu, and I can't find any other way of bring it up.

I'm using the version installed by Unity if that makes a difference.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately there is no way to change the default search behaviour in MonoDevelop (at least not in relation to case sensitivity). But what you may not know is, you control the case sensitivity with the search string that you use. A la emacs (for those old-school programmers out there).

That is, enter a search string that is all lowercase (say, 'monodevelop'), and search will be case *insensitive*. So it would find the pattern 'MonoDevelop'.

But as soon as you enter a capital somewhere in your search string (say, 'Monodevelop'), the search will become case *sensitive*. So it will no longer find that pattern 'MonoDevelop'.

Hopefully that helps!